# Rails 4 - Rename primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am hooking into an existing database to make some simple scaffolds for administration.  The naming convention they used is table_id.  So I am needing to modify the default primary key from "id", to "customer_id", for example.  I am also hoping to be able to use rails scaffolding with this change, without having to rewire everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide:  http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

And it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont wanna do that.

Id's are for database only, in Rails you can use a Foreign-key, and say something like

Costumer has_many : XXX
 and
XXX belongs_to : Costumer

that you give you a 1-n relation on the database meaning XXX needs a consumer to exist.

answering why you dont wanna change that, is because your database will not know how to behaviour after that change ( if possible at all ), and how would you search for a item on your new scaffold without and ID? since the ID is the Costumer ID

if you dont know how to give foreign keys, [click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#highlighter_935756)

Comment: The update of records will fail, if there is no column "id" to reference though, right?  The database I am connecting to, has customer_id as a primary key.  If I run a rails update or destroy, for id=45, it will not find a record.

Comment: you can add collum to database as a solution [check it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#highlighter_783751). to answer you exacly i don't know exacly how rails database work, but i would guess no, and i would not advise you to mess with that.
then you would have an issue finding by ID, it would be just too messy ( if it is possible). can you imagin? *something*find_by(id = costumer_id) if you ware searching something else and not your costumers? using the same ID for 2 tables that represent different things.. hmm.. kinda messy

Comment: example.. lets say that for every costumer you have products.. how would you access producs id? products.costumer_id? why not use this costumer_id as foreing key?. how would you store those products? and order? or search for  specifics? costumer_id will be not in the perfect order on your products table.. meaning that on your product one it would be ( for example) costumer_id 3, then on you second product it would be costumer_id 1.. so your table would be not in the order it needs to be in order to find by id
 can you imagine if you have 1000 products? and the ID is not from 1-1000 ?

Comment: you database would need to go element per element.. what about 1 million? databases (a bit information that i know) one of the finding methods is, if you give the ID of the items you want to take , your database will go the middle and if the the id of that element is greater or smaller comparing to the giving id, and according to that, will search up or down.. and so on and so on